# Problem with Laravel generating too many queries

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I'm just about at my whit's end here. I've been tasked with optimizing a system because pages are loading too slowly. The system is built on Laravel 5.5 (yeah I know not the latest version, but that's a problem for another day). I've installed Clockwork to get a better feel for what could be causing things to be so slow and literally fell off my seat. The load of a single page generated 10412 queries in the database (you read that right, 10000 queries to load a single page)!!!!!

Anyway, I tweaked relationships so that things could be properly lazy/eager loaded when necessary and that divided things by three... but that's still a lot considering how little information is currently displayed.

So I went on to try and tackle another problem they have: They defined custom attributes inside models that fetch informations from three or four layers of relationships. Here's a "simple" example:

```
ride-->(departureStop, destinationStop)-->(state, event, city)
```

This path is to resolve the "getNameAttribute()" defined inside the Ride model. So in essence, Laravel generates 5 queries just to calculate the name of a ride (said name being something like "Ottawa, On to Toronto, On"). Of course, being an attribute, this means that we get those 5 queries FOR EVERY INSTANCE OF THE RIDE MODEL. And that's just one attribute, there are dozens of them just like this.

Oh and just to add to the fun, we're also using the compoship package because some tables have composite primary keys.

I'm not sure what to include in terms of code here since everything is such tangled mess but every suggestion you can throw at me will be more than welcome.

Comment: You need to eager load whatever relationships that `getNameAttribute()` method is calling. You try using `Model::preventLazyLoading()` to force this, and show you where it's trying to lazy load. https://laracasts.com/series/jeffreys-larabits/episodes/3

Comment: Sounds like what I see frequently with use of ORMs. Definitely need to resolve the "identity map" stuff described, avoid pulling back the same data repeatedly. Beyond that, is there any cache layer?

Comment: @jszobody I can't use this feature, I'm on Laravel 5.5, it doesn't exist. That being said, I'll try to eager load the relationship with the model, but I doubt it'll do much good

Comment: as I thought, I added `protected $with = ['stop'];` in order to eager load the relationship and I jump from 668 to 726 queries

Comment: Without showing any specific code, you're asking us to just guess. You have a lazy-loading issue, but no one can provide you any specific help without seeing your code.